# Why cmake .. -GXcode does not generate makefile

Tags: xcode, cmake

I wrote a CMakeLists.txt file to compile a simple "hello word" example.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

#Declaration du projet
project(MYfirstcamke)

#declaration de l'executable
add_executable(
  my_executable
  main.cpp)
```

When I type cmake, It generates a makefile but when I use cmake .. -GXcode. I did not get a makefile. What is the problem?

Comment: Why do people still require version 2.6? I would expect new code to use 3.0 or maybe 2.8.something. Some popular tutorials must be outdated so badly...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know CMake either, however I would have expected `-GXcode` to generate an Xcode project (a `.xcodeproj` "file").

Xcode doesn't use `Makefile`s.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10439686)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk The question is "When I type cmake, It generates a makefile but when I use cmake .. -GXcode. I did not get a makefile".  My answer is "it doesn't generate a Makefile as Xcode doesn't use Makefiles".

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. -GXcode doesn't generate makefile by design. use Xcode to build the project instead

Answer (score 0):

It's `-G Xcode`, not `-GXcode`.

And the path should come after all the options, i.e.`cmake -G whatever ..` rather than `cmake .. -G whatever`.